# Modal does not appear on list item click

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

I am trying to display a modal when a list item is clicked.
I set the state to false initially, then when a list item is clicked it sets the setModalVisible state to true and the modal should display.
However, even though the state is true, checked by debugging, the modal does not display.

Initial State

```
this.state = {
      setModalVisible: false,
    };
```

Render List Item and toggle onPress

```
renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <ListItem bottomDivider={true} 
      onPress={() => this.showModal(item)}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}} margin={5}>
          <Avatar margin={5} rounded source={{uri: item.logo_url}} />
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text margin={50}>{item.rank}</Text>
            <Text margin={50} style={styles.cryptoTitle}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.cryptoPrice}> {'$' + item.price} </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }
```

Show Modal Function

```
showModal(item) {
    this.setState({setModalVisible: true});
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          visible={this.state.setModalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.setState({setModalVisible: false});
          }}>
          <Text> Modal is Visible !</Text>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Are you using a framework like Vue.js? Please add the tag for your framework.

Comment: @Barmar using react native, sorry thought i tagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not add the `Modal` in the Item. Returning the modal inside the `onPress` method would not add it to the tree:

```
renderItem(item) {
    return (
    <View>
      <ListItem bottomDivider={true} 
      onPress={() => this.showModal(item)}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}} margin={5}>
          <Avatar margin={5} rounded source={{uri: item.logo_url}} />
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text margin={50}>{item.rank}</Text>
            <Text margin={50} style={styles.cryptoTitle}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.cryptoPrice}> {'$' + item.price} </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ListItem>
         {this.state.setModalVisible ? <Modal // put the modal somewhere suitable
          animationType="slide"
          visible={this.state.setModalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.setState({setModalVisible: false});
          }}>
          <Text> Modal is Visible !</Text>
        </Modal> : null}
    </View>
    );
  }
```

Then the `showModal` simply updates the state:

```
showModal(item) {
    this.setState({setModalVisible: true});
}
```

Comment: when I try to add the <View> {this.state.modalVisible ? etc ... I get this error : JSX expressions must have one parent element.

Comment: @FrankBoccia please check the updated answer, you can put the modal view wherever you want

Answer (score 1):

First, the callback passed to onPress will not render the jsx you are returning.

The best approach is to update the state and based on the new one, render items

```js
showModal(item) {
    this.setState({ selectedItem : item });
}
```

```js
// render the modal somewhere in the parent component

<View>
 <List
 />
 {selectedItem && (
   <Modal
     animationType="slide"
     visible={!!this.state.selectedItem}
     onRequestClose={() => this. setState({ selectedItem : null})}>
          <Text> Modal is Visible !</Text>
   </Modal>
 )}
</View>
```